# lubuntu 16.10 halts on boot after software update on Dell Aspiron Mini 1018

Tags: boot, updates, 16.10

After a fresh install of lubuntu 16.10 on a dell aspiron mini 1018, the system asks to update the software. However the system doesn't boot anymore after this upgrade and halts with a blank screen. When I reset the system and boot ij recovery mode, it boots until the recovery menu and afyer the 'resume' option it halts at 'Starting Load/Safe RF Kill Switch Status.' A few lines before it says that it is activing swap, but does not show the green 'OK'

Any suggestions how to fix this issue and/or how to troubleshoot this further?

Regards,

Elco